# .htaccess redirect file request to PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect request of *.pe files to admin.php and pas the requested file as argument.

ex: the user request "site.com/dir/file.pe" and it will be redirected to "admin.php?file=file.pe"

I tryed:

```
<files *.pe> 
ErrorDocument 403 /login/db/admin.php?file=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</files>
```

but PHP's $_GET['file'] returns "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}"

.htaccess isn't passing the name, it's passing the %{REQUEST_FILENAME} as string, not the var.

How could I make it work?

thx

Comment: You need `mod_rewrite` to work with variables…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try it in your .htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.pe$ admin.php?file=$1.pe
```